# SonicWall TZ190 Enhanced VPN issues

Tags: firewall, sonicwall

I am using a SonicWall TZ190 and a Cisco device (I don't know the specs of this device. I will try to get it ASAP) to initiate an Office to Office VPN link. The tunnel will stay active for days, but randomly once a week or once every two weeks, the connection will drop. When I check the logs in the sonicwall device, it gives me a "IPSec (ESP) packet dropped" error around this time. The only way to get the link back up is ping the remote network from a device on our LAN. Once I do the ping, the VPN tunnel is active again. Does anyone have any ideas why this would keep disconnecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved this problem, but I am not going to mark complete until we have tested the VPN for a week.

The Sonicwall TZ 190 was on firmware 4.0.3.4, so I updated to 4.2.1. This seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: The only way I have been able to solve this issue is to setup a ping to run every 5 minutes from the server using the site to site.

Answer (score 0):

It could just be the Internet conditions or the ISPs at either end. VPNs at the end of everything are "best effort" connectivity options when the general ISP services themselves are basically best effort too, otherwise it would be a private circuit with some SLA in place.

Is seems like your VPN configuration is doing what it is suppose to, recover when there is traffic between the points.